# Setting up a simple proxy

Tags: proxy, http

I'm going to China for a week, and I'd prefer to be able to watch YouTube while I'm there. Since it's blocked, I presume I'm going to need a proxy. I have a Mac and a Linux box at home that I can use, but I'm not sure how complicated setting up a proxy is. From what I understand, I should be able to do it with a browser that supports HTTP 1.1 CONNECT if I connect to my machine at home. Can I do this, and if so, what browser can I use, or if I have misunderstood something, do I have any other simple solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The latency for web browsing is going to be very high and thus very slow if you are going to tunnel all the way to your house and then back out to the internet. You may as well set up a VPN connection, or take advantage of a free VPN service such as [Hotspot Shield](http://hotspotshield.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[tinyproxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinyproxy) works well if its for your own use - i'd suggest using a non standard port, tieing it up with a dyndns service, and using proxy switcher on firefox to turn it on or off. Its fairly simple to set up on linux based system  (its commonly found i nrepositories) and unless you need to ip address restrict it, needs no setup.